# What is the relationship behind a master table and a transaction table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm currently developing the database design `MySQL` for a maven project, and I came across these key words from the requirement which was given to me. Went through some blogs and posts regarding this but couldn't identify a clear thought on this.

Would be great if I could get a basic idea on these two keywords and how can they be differentiated? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some applications, particularly financial applications, you have to be able to reproduce the changes you've made to the database.  The transaction table holds the changes.

Lets use a simple bank checking account as an example.  The master table would contain the customer id and the account balance.  The transaction table would contain the customer id, transaction date, check or debit number, a withdrawal or deposit flag, and the amount.

You could easily create a monthly bank statement from the transaction table.  An auditor can determine if the account balances on the master table can be recreated from the transaction table.

In short, a master table shows the current values, and a transaction table shows the history of the current values.